# Looking for an item: a crystal that stores memories, up to an entire personality?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, product-identification

I am looking for an item and its reference page: a crystal shard that stores memories, up to an entire personality. I believe this particular item comes from one of the forgotten realms books, or possibly a web enhancement.

If I recall correctly, it was listed in association with elves (or perhaps the cited original creator was an elf), it was NOT a homebrew or third party source,  and I think it was a magic item, rather than a psionic item.

Should be hand held in size, possibly a crystal shard around a human forearm length? It is not a spell, or power, and it is not the silver skull from Planescape, nor the thought bottle.

Please help me find the referenced item?

Answer (score 9):

***Lost Empires of Faerûn*** describes ***telkiiras*** as "powerful lore-gems worn by the leaders of the mightiest elf clans. Each *telkiira* holds the knowledge, skills, and sometimes even a fragment of personality from each of the elves who previously wore it" (155—6). A *telkiira* does ***over five hundred words*** worth of stuff therefore too long, in my opinion, to reproduce fairly here, yet I suspect these gems are what you're remembering.

Comment: Hmm. That matches the points given... however after pondering some more the item I am thinking of did not grant any stat bonuses, and was capable of storing the entirety of a person's knowledge, possibly including a virtual copy of the personality as well? I seem to recall that it could answer questions out loud, and would do so using the typical voice and phrasing of the creator. Assuming I am recalling correctly, that is.

Comment: @nijineko It's possible to conflate the *telkiira* with the spell [*soul shackles*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49006/8610) or the spell [*binding*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#binding). The *answers questions* aspect seems more common among spells than magic items. I look forward to other answers.

Comment: Not the amulet of spirit storing, either.