# What happens to clones of a deepspawn created if/when the deepspawn dies?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, dungeons-and-dragons, lore

I am running a D&D 5E homebrew campaign where a powerful creature akin to a deepspawn is consuming and creating spawn of powerful beings in various governments and organizations to puppet a growing portion of civilization.

Assuming my players succeed in finding and destroying this creature, what have past editions and/or D&D literature said about the fate of the spawn it had created?

Since this is homebrew, I know I can pretty much do whatever I want, but I'm looking for insights into how to handle it so I have a plan in place.

I only have access to the *Lost Empires of Faerun* 4E book regarding them, and though it goes into detail about how the spawn are created and what the spawns' capabilities are, it does not mention anything about the spawns' existence after the deepspawn is slain.

Any examples from D&D literature or rulebooks would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Note: [*Lost Empires of Faerun*](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/28446/Lost-Empires-of-Faerun-35) seems to be a 3.5e book, not 4e.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The spawn appear to survive.

The D&D 3.5 adventure module *Expedition to Undermountain*, p.107, describes the result of slaying a deepspawn:

> If the PCs kill or drive away the deepspawn, they each gain a story award of 250 XP, in addition to the combat XP. They have eliminated a creature that could repopulate this section of Undermountain with dangerous creatures. If they do not defeat it but negotiate for safe passage through its territory, give each PC a 100 XP story award.

Note the lack of any special rule for what happens to the deepspawn's offspring. They don't die or explode or anything; killing the deepspawn just prevents it from producing more.

The AD&D 2e *Elminster's Ecologies*, p. 30-31, *The Thunder Peaks and he Storm Horns*, suggests that the allegiance of the offspring is due to some psychic control or influence, at least partly. Defeating one might impede the cohesion of a group of the offspring, and they would no longer have a leader, though there are no game rule mechanics that specifically cover this. However, they are self-willed, sentient beings, not puppets of the deepspawn, and can continue to fight and live normally without their creator.

Past rules for the deepspawn, particularly 3e's *Monsters of Faerûn* and 2e's *Monstrous Compendium*, also fail to mention any special rule for what happens to the offspring when the deepspawn dies. They merely no longer have a leader.

Comment: Killing it prevents the deepspawn from producing more *and* frees the spawn from the control of its deepspawn. (Note that a similar conclusion is reached by [this answer for *3.5*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/135619/8610).) Also, *Lost Empires of Faerûn* includes the *3.5* revision of the deepspawn; it may be worth referencing that instead of *Monsters of Faerûn*.